# define symbolic variables from a cell array of characters matlab symbolic math

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am very new to symbolic math Toolbox.

I am trying to create a symbolic math equations with the help of GUI. I am getting all the input variables from the user. I am either saving them as a cell array or normal matrix form.

Now how can I convert each variable as a symbolic variables. I have tried below codes but not working to my requirements.

```
cell2sym(cellArray)
```

also using for loop for each element

```
for i = 1:length(cellarray)
    variables{i} = sym(cellarray{i});
end
```

Comment: Why don't the two methods work? What errors are you getting? Other resolutions may exist if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: cell2sym converts the complete cell array to symbolic array but not individual symbolic variables. I have to call them back as an element of the symbolic array. when I call the individual variable i am getting the error as Undefined function or variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works with eval function, thank you

```
for i = 1: length(cellarray)
    eval(sprintf('syms(''%s'')',cellarray{i}))
end
```